# Getting real-time audio data from and to a Bluetooth device via Python

Tags: python, audio, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project and everything is going well except for one part. This troublesome part requires me to send and receive real-time audio between my raspberry pi 4 and Bluetooth earphones. I saw a similar post like this one: [Reading input sound signal using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344649/reading-input-sound-signal-using-python). However, this doesn't fit my situation since there isn't a physical connection between the two devices since it's occurring through Bluetooth.

How can I send my processed audio data to a pair of earphones and have that device send audio data back to my Pi system using Python? It would be awesome if there were some packages and well-documented examples.

Bluetooth headphones I've been using: [https://www.amazon.com/Skullcandy-Sesh-True-Wireless-Earbud/dp/B0857JLRFJ/ref=asc_df_B0857JLRFJ/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=459477192655&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8647089529284755064&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9033299&hvtargid=pla-923127348415&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0857JLRFJ)

Comment: What kind of bluetooth device are we talking about?

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a normal set of headphones you need to implement the **Bluetooth Classic Handsfree Profile** (HFP). [this](https://github.com/littlecraft/phony) library could help you, but I'm not sure since the library expects you to have a audio card to stream to. But maybe it's a start! Another [example](https://github.com/Nikolay-Kha/BluetoothAudio) shows only the audio streaming to a headset.

If this does not work you might be better of connecting the headphones directly to the Raspberry Pi and getting the audio from the system.